# Remove Problematic File from Drobo5N (NAS)

Tags: unix, drobo

For some reason I have some files on a Drobo5N, which is a NAS, that were copied over from my Mac.  They have a filename issue:

```
alpha:bravo:charlie.txt
```

That filename structure messes with all of the `Linux` commands that would deal with said file, including `rm`, `cp` and `mv`.  So I'm not sure what to do.  I'm using the terminal as well as the Mac GUI.

Any ideas how I can delete these files?  I don't have sudo access.

Cheers

Comment: If you’re using a GUI, can you not right click (control+click) and press “move to trash”?

Comment: @NoahL It's the very same underlying unix command.  The file syntax confuses the bash command, so there is no file to move, according to the OS.  Hence the issue.

Comment: Ah gahhh that’s annoying

Comment: Try deleting or renaming the files by enclosing them in quotes: `rm "alpha:bravo:charie.txt"` or `mv "alpha:bravo:charie.txt"`. [This page](https://kb.iu.edu/d/abao) at Indiana University has a slew of other suggestions.

Comment: @IconDaemon Was a great idea, which got me into trying some escaping, but none of them worked, even a `move`.

Comment: One of the ideas is to make the files available through FTP!

Comment: Yes, I'm thinking of that.  Not sure if I want to go through all that trouble.

Comment: It's a Mac peripheral on a Mac LAN, asking about any solutions including the Mac GUI and the Mac terminal, about files sent to it from a Mac.

Comment: Finder won't let you use a colon in a file name in the first place, so how did you manage it? Anyway... when you said you tried escaping, you mean `\:` ? Also, did you try `alpha/bravo/charlie.txt` just in case, or even try escaping that... `alpha\/bravo\/charlie.txt`?

Comment: @Tetsujin - The files in question may have come from another operating system that supports using Unicode characters that aren't literal colons, like the fullwidth colon, `U+FF1A`  or the Modifier Letter Colon, `U+A789`. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10386344/how-to-get-a-file-in-windows-with-a-colon-in-the-filename) at Stackoverflow goes into some detail.

Comment: It was inside a package on Mac OSX.  Nobody has ever been on my Drobo5N.  It is inside a package.  Anyway, since last posting, the `:`'s turned into question marks with boxes around them.  They got deleted just fine.  Looking through other subdirectories now.

Comment: Progress! I'm glad that the problem _seems_ to be going away. Huzzah!

Comment: Hah...another one of those strange days.  They line up sometimes.  Thanks for the notes.  Something tripped something.